# Adding a new page in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I created 2 pages, one for logging in with facebook and another one for slider. And in slider, I've got a button. When that button is pressed, I want it to go to a new page.
Here are the states:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider
        .state('root', {
            url: '',
            controller: 'rootCtrl',
            data: { 
                authenticate: false
            }
        })
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'home.html',
            controller: 'homeCtrl',
            data: {
               authenticate: true
            }
        })
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'login.html',
            controller: 'loginCtrl',
            data: {
                authenticate: false
            }
        })
        .state('balldrop', {
            url: '/balldrop',
            templateUrl: 'balldrop.html',
            controller: 'ballCtrl',
            data: {
                authenticate: true
            }
        })
    ;

    // Send to login if the URL was not found
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
})
```

Here is ballDrop.html:

```
<body ng-controller="ballCtrl">

  <ion-view>
    <img src="img/present.png">
    <img src="img/past.png">
    <img src="img/future.png">      
  </ion-view>

</body>
```

But when I add new router for balldrop, the ionic live server displays a blank page. Where is the error?

Comment: Have you created the `ballCtrl` controller? What error is throwing your browser console?

Comment: it's not clear, at what page you are right now? I mean your default page is login.html but what is shown here is ballDrop.html. and the what is the complain in chrome debugger?

Comment: drop a plunker instead for better understanding

Comment: I'm currently in home page. And I want to go to balldrop page from home page.

Comment: When I create ballCtrl controller, the whole ionic serve page becomes blank, when I comment that ballCtrl controller, the home page appears.

Answer (score 0):

check for the error in Chrome dev tools console. Gives an idea what's missing.